# Find the coordinate of the first value in a worksheet [openpyxl]

Tags: excel, openpyxl

In a workbook
At any active worksheet. how can I find the coordinate of the first cell with any kind of value in it?. And also for the last cell

Example:

At cell "D15"
Its a table made of 15 columns (right) and 50 rows (down)

Is there a way to get..

Start "D15"
End "S66"
--> range "D15:S66"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within `openpyxl`, you have `min_row`, `min_column`, `max_row` and `max_column`. Assuming you have some form of a table in range `D15:S66`, the values will be `min_column = 4` for '**D**', `min_row = 15`, `max_column=19` for '**S**' and `max_row=66`. Sample code is here.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
data_file='test.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(data_file)
ws = wb.worksheets[0]

print(ws.min_row, ws.min_column, ws.cell(ws.min_row,ws.min_column).value)
print(ws.max_row, ws.max_column, ws.cell(ws.max_row,ws.max_column).value)
```

**Output**

```
15 4 Header1
66 19 33333
```